# $a, b \in S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ are not antipodal points then $0 \not \in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $a, b \in S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ are not antipodal points, that is, $b \neq -a$. How to prove that
$$0 \not\in [a,b] =\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}:x=(1-t)a+tb, t \in [0,1]\}.$$

Geometrically, it is easy to see, but I don't know how to prove this. I tried to argue by contradiction, that is, there exists $t_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $(1-t_0)a+t_0b=0$ (note that for $t=0$ and $t=1$ we have $(1-t)a+tb=a \neq 0$ and $(1-t)a+tb=b\neq 0$), so $(t_0-1)a=t_0b$. But I don't know how to conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Prove the contrapositive. If $0\in[a,b]$, then there is a $t\in(0,1)$ such that $0=(1-t)a+tb$. ($t$ cannot be $0$ or $1$, since then either $a$ or $b$ would be zero.) Solve for $b$ and use the fact that $|a|=|b|=1$ to conclude.

Comment: $1\neq(t-1)/t$. $b$ doesn't need to be equal to $1$, but its _modulus_ does. That is, $1=|b|=|(t-1)/t|\cdot|a|$.

Comment: How we get a contradiction from $1=\frac{|t-1|}{|t|}$?

Answer (score 1):

suppose that $0\in [a,b]$ and $a\neq \pm b$, then $[a,0]\subseteq [a,b]$ and the line $\{ta| t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ containts the set $[a,b]$. In particular, there is a real element $u$ such that $ua=b$, but  $\|b\|=1$, then $u=\pm1,$ so $a=\pm b$, which makes a contradiction.